# Weird behavior of Finder Sync Extension's tool bar item menu

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, appstore-sandbox, findersync

I am building a macOS app with Finder Sync Extension, which adds a tool bar item to the Finder.

I created the tool bar item menu like this:

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForMenuKind:(FIMenuKind)whichMenu {
    NSMenu *menu = [NSMenu new];

    NSURL *URL = ...// Create a NSURL dynamically

    NSMenuItem *item = [NSMenuItem new];
    [item setTitle:@"foo"];
    [item setRepresentedObject:URL];
    [item setTarget: self];
    [item setAction:@selector(itemClicked:)];

    [menu addItem:item];

    return menu;
}

- (void)itemClicked:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"%@", item.representedObject);
}
```

The item did show up with the title "foo", but when I click on it `(null)` was printed out.

I also tried creating a subclass of `NSMenuItem` with `@property (NSURL*) URL`, and set the URL property when I create the item, but after the click the URL property become nil again.

So what went wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu and menu items shown when you right click in Finder are **copies** of the menu items you provide in  `menu(for menu: FIMenuKind)`.

Not all of your menu item's properties will survive the copy, leading to the `nil` value you're getting for `representedObject`. An NSMenuItem subclass will also definitely not be preserved.

See the FinderSync header for more information from Apple:

> `optional public func menu(for menu: FIMenuKind) -> NSMenu?`
>
> Specific menu item properties are used: `title`, `action`, `image`, and `enabled`.
>
> Starting in 10.11: `tag`, `state`, and `indentationLevel` also work, and submenus are allowed.

Using the menu item's `title` string or `tag` to determine the needed URL is probably the best available option.

Comment: Thx! I end up saving the URLs as an array in NSUserDefaults and set each item's tag as the index of its URL in the array.