# Why does custom NSMenuItem (MyNSMenuItem) perform action sender still to be NSMenuItem?

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenuitem

I have create a new `NSMenuItem` class shows in the following:

```swift
class FilerNSMenuItem: NSMenuItem {
    private var defaultFileExtension: String = ""

    var fileExtension: String {
        get { return defaultFileExtension }
        set { defaultFileExtension = newValue }
    }
}
```

And I create a menu item using following code:

```swift
item = FilerNSMenuItem(title: title, action: #selector(SomeActions(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
menuItem.submenu?.items.append(item)
```

The `SomeActions` is defined in the following:

```swift
@objc func SomeActions(_ sender: FilerNSMenuItem) {
    if sender.fileExtension != "" {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, when I tap the menu item, and the error occurred in the `SomeAction`, the `sender` here is still `NSMenuItem` not `FilerNSMenuItem` and error says **Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

How can I deal with this problem so that the `sender` is `FilerNSMenuItem` not `NSMenuItem`. Thank you.

Comment: Is the action method `SomeActions` or `newFile`? Where is the menu, in the menu bar of the app?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, is SomeActions. It's a FinderSync app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird behavior of Finder Sync Extension's tool bar item menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501281/weird-behavior-of-finder-sync-extensions-tool-bar-item-menu)

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, but I hope to get a more elegant solution